# Regex Replace for [- to +] Integers in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex in order to format user enter text in numerical,
Negative as well as positive number.

I've tried this pattern

```
[^-.0-9]
```

but not working as expected and string like this -00-000---0000 is accepted.

after looking on internet, I found this pattern

```
 @"^-\d *\.?\d +$"
```

but Regex Replace is not working for pattern like this.
I'm pasting code down too.

```cs
var text = Regex.Replace(string, @"^-\d *\.?\d +$", "");
```

The above code is not working.
If I enter any string variable text will contain exactly same string that I entered without formatting or converting it into regex pattern.

Is the problem with the code or the pattern I can't understand.

I want something like this

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| -9999 | -9999 |
| 99ab9 | 999 |
| 676y7 | 6767 |
| 99.0hu | 99.0 |
| -99.00 | -99.00 |

Comment: Please provide some example inputs.

Comment: Could u add some input examples and expected results?

Comment: I've added some input cases for better understanding

Comment: There may be multiple possible ways to clean up an invalid string. E.g, should `9-9` be turned into `-9` or `99`? On a side note, it is a terrible user experience when symbols you type disappear according to arbitrary rules, please don't do that.

Comment: I know but it is kinda requirement. Also i'm not able to get why that replace function in not working.

Comment: So what are you going to do about that requirement? You still have to resolve the ambiguity in some way. The replace is not working because that regex describes a valid string, so it can only be used to test whether a string is valid. It would be a much more complicated regex to describe *invalid characters* within the string so that those could be removed.

Comment: Also it should be number only field with exception to "-" at starting and one "." in between but not necessary. 
i think you might understand why i need it.

Comment: Well i have an idea if regex doesn't work to use a lot of "contains" function and if statement, but well regex looks a lot cleaner and this is the main reason i'm opting for it

Comment: I think i have a solution, just working out some issues with line breaks then ill post it once its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So out of your input string, you want to keep:

- the first hyphen that has no other hyphens, digits or dots in front of it
  That is `(?<![0-9.-].*)-`
- the first dot that does not have other dots in front of it
  That is `(?<!\..*)\.`
- all digits
  That is `[0-9]`

This directly corresponds to a simple regex:

```
@"[0-9]|(?<!\..*)\.|(?<![0-9.-].*)-"
```

which you then use:

```cs
string[] inputs = { "-00-000---0000", "-9999", "99ab9", "676y7", "99.0hu", "-99.00", "9-9" };

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Regex.Matches(input, @"[0-9]|(?<!\..*)\.|(?<![0-9.-].*)-").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)));
}
```

Note that there may be multiple possible ways to clean up an invalid string. E.g., should `9-9` be turned into `-9` or `99`? This particular implementation happens to go with `99`.

On a side note, it is a terrible user experience when symbols you type disappear according to arbitrary rules, please don't do that.

Comment: Love this solution. Didn't think about lookaheads or simply matching every valid character individually and then concatenating them all

Answer (score 0):

So really regex isn't quite designed to do this type of thing however it is just about possible using capture groups and calling the regex repeatedly.

I will first explain my regex, when it works, when and why it doesn't work and then how you can make it work

### The Regex

Here it is:

`(^[+-]?)(?:([0-9.]+)|[^\.\d\n\s]*)+`

And now to break it down

- `(^[+-]?)` is responsible for looking at the beginning of the line for one or zero instances of '+' or '-'. The brackets around this are a capture group meaning if we found a symbol here we will return it in our first 'capture group'
- `(?:)+` Represents a 'non-capture group' which can occur one or more times. This means we want to group everything in here together, and apply the '+' quantifier too it, but we don't want to return it as a capture group
- Next we have an or `|` between two different regex's
- `([0-9.]+)` is where we 'capture' your actual digits, this says we can have any digit or a decimal place one or more times. Once again this is in a capture group meaning we want to return the results of this.
- `[^\.\d\n\s]*` The other option in the or is to match anything that **is not** a digit (sorry I have changed notation to using \d here my bad), a line break, or white space. This will match any characters that are randomly in the middle of the string like examples 2 and 3

### Why it isn't perfect

This regex will work perfectly in anything where it is only required to capture one group of digits, this is all but examples 2 and 3. However capture groups in regex can only return a single group, so their behaviour is to always return the last group.

you can see this at this [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/wy3W4i/1)

Doing this otherwise would be recursive in nature, which is a behavior Regular Expressions are un-able to match (for this you would need some more advanced language parsing like Backus Naur form)

### The Solution

While the regex it's self is not recursive, you can call it repeatedly and collect all the capture groups! and this regex should be friendly to doing this

Using C#'s regex libary you should be able to extract the returned capture groups, you will need to do this and then remove the extracted capture (dont know if C# can do this it's self) in a loop until running the regex on the string results in no new capture. Storing all these captures in a list will give you all the components you need to reconstruct the desired string.

(Note that as regex matches the *last* instance of the capture it finds, the digits will be in reverse order in the result. You could fix this by seperating any non-numeric/decimal point results from the list and then reversing the list and adding the +/- back to the beginning if there was one)